# How to print the elements of a dictionary except a specified element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
seatList1 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10 }
```

I made the above dictionary as a airline seat list. Once users choose an empty seat and enter their name and other details in, the value of seat they choose will become their names, for example:

Before they choose:

```
1: 1
```

After:

```
1: Tom
```

The following is my identify program. 'Detail' is a string which included "Passenger's" details.

```
while (True): 

  seatNum = int(input("Enter the seat number:"))
  if isinstance(seatList1[seatNum], str):
    print("This seat has been ordered, please enter another one.")
  else:
    print("Success")
    seatList1[seatNum] = detail

    print(seatList1)
    break
```

So that this program can identify a seat is empty or not by its value is a string or integer. But the problem is, I want this program can print the empty seat at the first time, just like this(pretend number 1 seat has been taken):

```
The available seats are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

So that "passengers" can know which seats are available for them to choose. Is there a way for me to solve this problem without writing more list? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use a dict of int:bool pairs, or even just a list of bools?

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, I think it's better to change the design. What is `if isinstance(seatList1[seatNum], str):` meant to do? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I don't understand what you mean by _solve this problem without write more list_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same logic as your code above. If User already booked that seat, then value for that seat number in `seatList1` will be string. You can just do -

```
for k, v in seatList1.items():
    if not isinstance(v, str):
        print (k)
```

If you want to print the available seats as a comma seperated string, you can use `join()` -

```
",".join(str(k) for k, v in seatList1.items() if not isinstance(v, str))
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you like the idea of using a set for empty seats, and a dictionary for taken seats?  That way, you don't have to check the type of the key returned for a seat, which is not always a robust choice in a duck-typing language such as Python.

```
max_seat_number = 10
empty_seats = set(range(1, max_seat_number + 1))
taken_seats = {}
print("Empty seats : ", empty_seats)
while True:
    name = input("Enter the passenger name (or type 'quit'): ")
    if name == "quit":
        break
    while True:
        seat_requested = int(input("Enter the seat number : "))
        try:
            empty_seats.remove(seat_requested)
            taken_seats[seat_requested] = name
            break
        except KeyError:
            print("Seat", seat_requested, "is not available.")
            print("Empty seats : ", empty_seats)
    print("Taken seats :", taken_seats)
    print()
```

Here's some sample output.  More error checking and prompting could be added.

```
Empty seats :  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Enter the passenger name (or type 'quit'): John
Enter the seat number : 5
Taken seats : {5: 'John'}

Enter the passenger name (or type 'quit'): George
Enter the seat number : 8
Taken seats : {5: 'John', 8: 'George'}

Enter the passenger name (or type 'quit'): Mark
Enter the seat number : 5
Seat 5 is not available.
Empty seats :  {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}
Enter the seat number : 2
Taken seats : {5: 'John', 8: 'George', 2: 'Mark'}

Enter the passenger name (or type 'quit'): Mary
Enter the seat number : 9
Taken seats : {5: 'John', 8: 'George', 2: 'Mark', 9: 'Mary'}

Enter the passenger name (or type 'quit'): quit
```

Comment: @alkasm, you are correct, and I changed my code.  While I'm making changes, I also made seat counting start from one instead of zero.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to know how long I spent on this, I might have gotten slightly carried away.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional


class Seat(NamedTuple):
    available: bool = True
    data: Optional[str] = None


seats = dict.fromkeys((str(elem) for elem in range(1, 11)), Seat())

print(seats)

while True:
    print(f"\nCurrent seat data:\n{'seat number':<11}  {'available':<10}  {'data':<20}")
    for seat_num, seat_obj in seats.items():
        print(f'{seat_num!s:<11}  {seat_obj.available!s:<10}  {seat_obj.data!s:<20}')
    seat_num_in = input('Enter the seat number: ')
    seats_dict_res = seats.get(seat_num_in)
    if not seats_dict_res:
        input('\nERROR: The seat number is invalid.\nPress ENTER to continue.')
    elif not seats_dict_res.available:
        input('\nERROR: That seat is not available.\nPress ENTER to continue.')
    else:
        passenger_name_in = input("Enter the passenger's name: ")
        seats[seat_num_in] = Seat(available=False, data=passenger_name_in)
```

This solution makes use of [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), which are adapted from the standard [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). The formatting is done with the new (ish) [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
print ([i for i in seatList1.keys() if isinstance(seatList1[i], int)])
```